# Array showing undefined as answer instead of showing object values

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I pass values of title and author, I want to check first whether any other value with the same title exists or not. If exists, then don't enter data into the empty array and if it doesn't exist then enter the data. But i get undefined as the answer. Where I am doing wrong.

```js
var add = (title, author) => {
  var i = 0;
  var notes = [];
  var note = {
    title,
    author
  };

  for (i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
    if (note.title === notes[i].title) {
      console.log('same entry');
    } else {
      notes.push(note);
    }
  };
  
  console.log(notes[i]);
};

add("TITLE", "AUTHOR")
```

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achive here, but clearly, notes.length is always 0 when you get to the for loop and thus it never starts

Comment: also, you should use for(var i ... ) or for(let i ... ), otherwise i will end up as a global variable

Comment: Furthermore, adding elements to an array while iterating over it at the same time is just asking for trouble :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a global `notes`, because for every call this array is empty. Theen you need to return the function if you found an entry with the same `title`.

At last push a new object if the title is not found in the array.

```js
var notes = [],                              // global or outside of the function
    add = (title, author) => {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
            if (title === notes[i].title) {  // check title
                console.log('same entry');
                return;                      // exit function if title exists
            }
        };
        notes.push({ title, author });       // no title found, add new object
    };
    
console.log(notes);

add('a', 'b');
console.log(notes);

add('a', 'b');
console.log(notes);

add('c', 'd');
console.log(notes);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Notes lenght will always be 0 in your case. Check if notes length 0 i.e first push, if true then add to notes else execute your logic.

```js
//take it out of function
var notes = [];     

var add = (title,author)=>{
   
//Check if notes length o if true the add to notes
var note={ title, author };
  if(notes.length ==0)
     notes.push(note);
  else{
      for(var i = 0; i < notes.length;i++){
          if(title ===notes[i].title)
              console.log('same entry');
          else
            notes.push(note);
      };
    };
  } 
  
add('Javascript','abc');
add('Javascript','xyz');
add('java','lmn');
console.log(notes);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have many problems in your code.
1-

```
var notes = [];
```

this line is initializing the notes array every time you call add(title, auther) which will make it empty every time. so you need to define it globally.

2-

```
for (i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
    if (note.title === notes[i].title) {
      console.log('same entry');
    } else {
      notes.push(note);
    }
  };
```

this part will push the note to the notes array for each element in the notes array which doesn't have the same title with the note one. which will lead to multiple adding for the same element.

follow the solution of the @Nina Scholz

Answer (score 0):

please check below code, I think this may fix your issue...

```js
var notes = [];

var add = (title, author) => {
  var i = 0;
  //var notes = [];    // declared globally  
  var note = {
    title,
    author
  };
  if (notes.length == 0) {
    notes.push(note);
  } // added this to add first record
  else {
    for (i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
      if (note.title === notes[i].title) {
        console.log('same entry');
      } else {
        notes.push(note);
      }
    };
  }
  console.log(notes[i]);
};

console.log(notes);

add('a', 'b');
console.log(notes);

add('a', 'b');
console.log(notes);

add('c', 'd');
console.log(notes);
```